# Angular 4 - How to call parent method from child component without EventEmitter?

Tags: angular

I have following hierarchy in my app:

```
AppComponent » ThemeComponent » HeaderNavComponent
```

The ThemeComponent has a method

```
   qrIconClicked(){

   }
```

I need to call this method from HeaderNavComponent.

How can I do that?

Comment: You may use the `Injector` to get an instance of the component: https://angular.io/api/core/Injector . That aside, you may reference the method on a `input` of your `HeaderNavComponent`, which will work as a "link" between parent and child. Alternatively, you can reference the entire `this` of the parent component and put it as an input of the child component. None of these last solutions should be good practices though, so I would personally stick with the Injector. Please check this aswell: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10448 (check sod's post). also, you may use ViewContainerRef

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by defining `@Output` type variable in your child `HeaderNavComponent` component and bubble and event when you want from the child which will be captured by the parent component `ThemeComponent` and fire a method `qrIconClicked()`

So your child component will look like

```
export class HeaderNavComponent {
   @Output() editDone = new EventEmitter<EditEvent>();

  onSubmit() {
    if (some condition) {
      this.editDone.emit('some value');
    } else {
      this.editDone.emit('other value');
    }
  }
}
```

As you raise `editDone` event from your child component, while calling your child component you can assign a function to call when that event will be emmitted.

```
<header-nav(editDone)="qrIconClicked($event)"><header-nav>
```

And finally you function will get value from child in the event passed to parent

```
   qrIconClicked(event: any){
     //event will hold value from chilld 
   }
```