# angular2 parent component reference in output

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new to angular 2 and I have been trying to get the value of an attribute of a parent component called form the @output implementation of the parent. Here is the code

ParentPage.ts

```
export class ParentPage {
    name: string;

    constructor(){ this.name = "john doe"; }

    handleChild(text){ 
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

ParentPage.html

```
<div child-component (childClick)="handleChild($event)"></div>
```

childComponent.ts

```
@Component( {
    selector: '[child-component]'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output() childClick = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.childClick.emit('event emitted');
    }
}
```

problem is `this.name` is undefined. how do i get the value of that attribute.

Comment: Try triggering the event in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: looks this for more details -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733130/angular-4-how-to-call-parent-method-from-child-component-without-eventemitter/46733329#46733329

Comment: i tried that, it didnt work

Comment: @ConnorsFan Is that really true? Angular.io says otherwise - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Comment: I just suggested to try it, to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending an event from child component, you need to catch that event and get (`name`) out of it.

for your case you are setting value in your `constructor`. I would say set the value of name in any of the angular lifecycle functions like `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.name = "john doe";
}

handleChild(event: any){ 
    console.log(event.name);
}
```

Comment: I don't need the value from the child. i need the value from the parent. the `this.name` is from the parent. `event.name` is undefined

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
   this.name = "john doe";
}` have you tried this

Comment: `ngOnInit() { this.name = "john doe"; }` in the parent didn't work too. still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<div child-component (childClick)="handleChild($event)"></div>
```

to this:

```
<child-component (childClick)="handleChild()"></child-component>
```

And since you are not interested in passing data from child to parent based on comments, change this:

```
this.childClick.emit('event emitted');
```

to this:

```
this.childClick.emit();
```